# Deploy java app to open with JRE

Tags: java, deployment, jar, export, bin

I wrote a Java app that I exported as an executable .jar.  When I run it on a mac, though, it says "java -jar app.jar is a command-line tool" and that the user has to install the JDK.

I know that since it's a jar, the user will have to have Java installed to run it, but is there a way to compile (as a .jar) it so that it can be opened with just the JRE or whatever comes pre-installed on mac?  Or do I have to package it somehow for the OS?

Comment: in terminal put java -jar app.jar.or you can write it as a bash as well

Comment: @Madhan that's the problem because in order to use the "java" command line tool, it says I need to have the JDK

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to use java from the command line, why doesn't it work?
>   I  have Oracle's version of the JRE installed.
>
> Installing a JRE from
>   Oracle does not update java -version symlinks or [add java](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml) to your
>   path. For this functionality, you must install the full JDK. See Mac
>   [command line info](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/version_manual.xml#cmdline).